# Replace letters with numbers as user types in a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have a JTextField for users to enter a serial number. The form of the serial number is such that it contains none of the letters I, O or S, since they look similar to 1, 0 and 5. What's the correct way to make it so that if the user types one of those letters, it enters the number instead?
e.g. The user types `AaOo0` and it goes into the JTextField as `Aa000`
To clarify, this should happen as the user types each character, not after they've finished typing and left the text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [DocumentFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html).

Something like :

```
AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument)jtextField.getDocument();
doc.setDocumentFilter(yourImplementationOfDocumentFilterWhichChangeOto0OnInsertAndReplace);
```

Comment: Man, that's much better than my crummy ol' listener based solution! +1

Comment: Interesting, I never knew about that solution.  I'd only seen solutions where you create a subclass of AbstractDocument to do the filtering.  Your approach is far superior (expresses the intent more clearly)